# Energy in different coordinates in central force motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, potential-energy

With reference to central force, we see that K.E has 2 terms in 2D cartesian cordinate but just 1 term in polar coordinates and potential energy has 1 term in cartesian but 2 terms in polar.

Basically magnitude of K.E and P.E can change with choice of coordinates? Doesn't it sound strange? Though i understand total energy is same in both cases.

Is it then possible to create a coordinate system with no kinetic energy just potential energy?

Comment: The magnitudes shouldn't change when you switch between polar and cartesian. Unless you make a mistake. ;)

Comment: $\frac12m\left(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\theta^2\right)$ has two terms.

Comment: Why are you referring to the “magnitude” of the kinetic and potential energies? They aren’t vectors.

Comment: It’s not clear what your confusion is since you omitted all math. You can write it with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: *potential energy has 1 term in cartesian but 2 terms in polar.* $-GMm/r$ has one term, not two.

Comment: @Ghoster  I know $\frac{m}{2}(\dot {r^2} + r^2 \dot {\theta^2})$ had two terms but the second one is replaced by $\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}$ in central force motion and note since it has no velocity terms but it has 'r' instead it now becomes a potential term and also there is an another U(r) which is original potential term we are familir with so total 2 potential and 1 K.E terms

Comment: From what you originally wrote, it isn’t obvious that you are talking about the effective potential, not the actual potential. I suggest that you edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: where L is angular momentum of particle defined by $L= mr^2\dot {\theta}$

Comment: @Ghoster *it isn’t obvious that you are talking about the effective potential, not the actual potential*  how is effective potential (in polar)different from actual potential(in spherical) if they both represent potential energy of the same particle? I thought they are same so i didn't mention it.   ..... can you answer this as an answer to this post?

Comment: Sorry, we can’t have an extended discussion in comments. I take back what I said about editing your question, since your original question has received an answer. You don’t want to make that answer invalid or obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

The equations of motion of a particle with mass $m$ under the influence of a central force are given by $$m \ddot{\mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}), \tag{1} \label{1}$$  where$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) =-\mathbf{\nabla} V(|\mathbf{r}|)=-V^\prime(|\mathbf{r}|) \frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|} \tag{2} \label{2}.$$ Eq. \eqref{1} is a system of three second order differential equations  requiring thus a total of six integrations. Using \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, it can easily be seen that the total energy $$E=\frac{m \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2}{2}+V(|\mathbf{r}|) \tag{3} \label{3}$$ and the three components of the angular momentum $$\mathbf{L}= m \mathbf{r} \times \dot{\mathbf{r}} \tag{4}, $$  are constants of motion, reducing the number of remaining integrations to $6-4=2$. Choosing a cartesian coordinate system where the angular momentum vector points in the positive $z$-direction, the motion of the particle is confined to the $x$-$y$ plane and $$E= \frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\right)+V\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right),\qquad  L\equiv L_z= m(x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}) \ge 0. \tag{5}$$ Switching to polar coordinates $$x= r \cos \theta, \quad y=r \sin \theta, \tag{6}$$ one obtains $$ E=\frac{m}{2} \left(\dot{r}^2+r^2 \dot{\theta}^2   \right)+V(r), \qquad L= m r^2 \dot{\theta}. \tag{7} \label{7}$$ The two remaing integrations in \eqref{7} can be disentangled by inserting $\dot{\theta}=L/mr^2$ into the first equation leading to $$E=\frac{m}{2}\dot{r}^2 +\underbrace{\frac{L^2}{2m r^2}+V(r)}_{V_{\rm eff}(r)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

In polar coordinates with respect to a central force, the kinetic energy in polar coordinates is given as:
$$K={1\over 2}m(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\theta^2).$$
And if the force is central $\vec F=f(r)\mathbf{\hat r}$, then the potential from which the force is derived will depend only on the radial coordinate:
$$\vec F=-\nabla V(r).$$
So in polar coordinates, the central force problem has a kinetic energy that depends on two variables and a potential that depends on one variable.

If the total energy has no kinetic energy terms then the mass in question is stationary. Thus, such a physical scenario corresponds to an object at the minimum of a potential well, or an object subject to some force of constraint which results in static equilibrium. If the object in question moves at a constant velocity, then it is possible to define an inertial coordinate system, i.e. the "rest frame" of the object such that it has no kinetic energy.

Comment: I understood the 'no K.E' part well but from my side, mistakenly i wasn't specific in the question about the potential enegy because i was convinced that in central force motion its obvious that $V_{eff}$ =potential energy of particle so i didn't mention $V_{eff}$ in my question, but considering that now, can it be proven that the values of 
respective energy are still same, though in different coordinates?

Comment: @AmitRai The total energy $E=T+V$ is a constant for this type of motion and it is independent of the coordinates chosen to work the problem.